# Get json output from Openpagerank API and TypeError

Tags: python, json, jupyter-notebook

```
import requests
import json

headers = {'API-OPR':'openpagerank API key'}
domain = 'https://www.hootsuite.com'
url = 'https://openpagerank.com/api/v1.0/getPageRank?domains%5B0%5D=' + domain
request = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

result = request.json()
print(result)
```

Output JSON:

```
output: {'status_code': 200, 'response': [{'status_code': 200, 'error': '', 'page_rank_integer': 7, 'page_rank_decimal': 7.2, 'rank': '451', 'domain': 'hootsuite.com'}], 'last_updated': '18th Oct 2020'}
```

I want to print the `page_rank_decimal`, for that I used
`print(result["response"]["page_rank_decimal"])` then it will give the
`TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not list` 
how to solve it?

Comment: Did you try `print(result["response"][0]["page_rank_decimal"])`?

Answer (score 0):

```
output: {'status_code': 200, 'response': [{'status_code': 200, 'error': '', 'page_rank_integer': 7, 'page_rank_decimal': 7.2, 'rank': '451', 'domain': 'hootsuite.com'}], 'last_updated': '18th Oct 2020'}
```

The response's structure is an array `[`. You have to specify an index. In this case, you could use `print(result["response"][0]["page_rank_decimal"])` because you only have one row in the response.

Answer (score 0):

You need to access a dictionary value in a list which is in a dictionary.

As you have done, printing the `result` have given you a dictionary.

If you try `result["response"]`, then you will get a list with 1 element `[{'status_code': 200, 'error': '', 'page_rank_integer': 7, 'page_rank_decimal': 7.2, 'rank': '451', 'domain': 'hootsuite.com'}]`. (The element inside the list is a dictionary.)

To access the "response" first element, use `result["response"][0]`. It will output `{'status_code': 200, 'error': '', 'page_rank_integer': 7, 'page_rank_decimal': 7.2, 'rank': '451', 'domain': 'hootsuite.com'}`

To access the value of `"page_rank_decimal"` in the dictionary, use `result["response"][0]["page_rank_decimal"]` and it will give your answer.